# Parse long double from string

Tags: parsing, floating-point, ocaml, static-analysis

I need to parse floating-point literals in C code using OCaml.

OCaml's float type is 64 bit. I have the string of the literal, its numeric value rounded to 64 bits and its kind (float, double or long double).

The problem are literals with a numeric value bigger than 64 bit:

1. long double literals
2. float literals with 'f'-suffix for which double rounding errors would occur if they wouldn't have the suffix.

OCaml's [arbitrary-precision module](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Num.html) can parse rational numbers from strings like "123/123", but not "123.123", "123e123", "0x1.23p-1" like they might appear in C.

Background: I do value analysis of C programs using [CIL](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~necula/cil/).

Double literals of any size and float literals with a numeric value that fits into 64 bit are always correctly represented. By rounding from double- to single-precision I can also reproduce [double rounding errors](http://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/).

Comment: What is a "C floating-point number" in your mind/context?

Comment: Nitpicker's corner: actually only on few platforms `long double` is 128 bit; on x86 it's usually 80 bit (the internal precision of the x87 FPU), and for VC++ it's just a regular `double` ([more info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double)).

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you mean by parsing the numbers.  Do you mean you just want to verify that the numeric constants are well formed?  Or do you want to translate them to a numeric value?  Then you have a representation problem as well as a parsing problem.

Comment: See edit. I need to get the numeric value of floating-point literals in C code. The parsing is independent of how long the registers actually are.

Comment: I find it a bit odd that someone who is interested especially in double rounding says something like: "OCaml's float type is 64 bit, so the float_of_string function works fine for C's float and double types." Function `float_to_string` does **not** work for single-precision floats, of course: http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2010/11/20/IEEE-754-single-precision-numbers-in-Frama-C

Comment: You may also want to know that `strtod()` and `strtof()` (the former used by OCaml, the second that you may interface for yourself) have longstanding bugs on Linux that show on those numbers that would exhibit the double rounding errors. I have been solving the same problem recently, but I didn't do `long double`, so I am not sure you'd be interested in my solution. Plus it's in Frama-C, with its common interface layer above Big_int/Zarith.

Comment: Updated the question. Even getting single-precision floats right requires me to parse literals with values bigger than 64 bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote my answer in the form of a [blog post](http://blog.frama-c.com/index.php?post/2011/11/18/Analyzing-single-precision-floating-point-constants)

To summarize some of the points here: you could interface `strtold()` and `strtof()` from OCaml. For the former, you would have to consider how you are going to store the result it produces, since there only is a point if `long double` is larger than `double` on your host architecture. There remains the problem that these functions are buggy in one of the most widely used C library. Very slightly buggy, but buggy for exactly the examples that are going to be of interest if you are doing this to study double rounding.

Another way is to write your own function, starting from [another post](http://www.exploringbinary.com/correct-decimal-to-floating-point-using-big-integers/) in the blog you refer to.

Finally, the phrase "Even getting single-precision floats right requires me to parse literals with values bigger than 64 bit" that you use in the comments is still a strange way to put it. The intermediate format(s) in which you can parse the representation of a single-precision float before you round it to single-precision **have to** be lossless, otherwise there will be double rounding. Double rounding may be more or less difficult to exhibit depending on the precision of the lossy intermediate format, but using 80 bits or 128 bits binary floating-point formats is not going to remove the problem, just make it more subtle. In the simple algorithm that I recommend, the intermediate format is a fraction of two multiprecision integers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the question in this question :)

Assuming that you need an ocaml parser for "C float literals" - the answer is - write one yourself, it is not very hard and you will have strict control on the implementation details and what "C float literal" actually means.

Comment: You're right, there's not really a question anymore. I hoped there would be an easier way than writing a parser myself.

Comment: I guess not, cause your task is rather specific.